# central workload identity pool for on-premise application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, workload-identity

We have implemented workload identity federation for authenticating on-prem apps to GCP. We are creating a pool per application.
Is it possible to have a single pool for all applications? Each application will be onboarded indivually to the federation provider but will be authenticated using a single pool.Can we create a single pool on GCP side to authenticate all the apps ?